# Backbone Marionette ItemView not firing event(using two templates)

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette ItemView which has two template which i want to open on a specific condition.
Backbone view is registering events for 1 template, but not firing for second template.

```
 var emailView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            initialize: function(){
          },
          getTemplate: function(){
            if(this.options.position == 'a'){
//load tempalte 2
              return template2;
            } else {
//load template 1
              return template;
            }
          },
          events: {
//event from second template, not firing
              'click #abcdef': 'a',
//event from first template, working
              'click #sendemail': 'b'
          },
          a: function(){
            alert("Hello");
          },
          b: function(){
            alert("Hellob");
          }
```

When i run template 1, event are working fine, but when i load template2, its not taking events for it.

Can guide me what i am doing wrong.

My 1st template:

```
<div id="emaildialog" title="" class="emaild">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row1">
            <button class="k-button" id="sendemail">Send</button>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
```

My 2nd template:

```
<div id="emailconfiguredialog" class="emaild" title="">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row1">
            <button class="k-button" id="abcdef">Update Email</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide the code for the templates?

Comment: @ne8il Updated code to show code for template.

Comment: I dont see an error on what you posted, I copied the code and its working on jsfiddle, perhaps the issue is somewhere else,http://jsfiddle.net/fYrhs/1/